# Debian removal of Google Drive folder without deleting its files

Tags: debian, synchronization, fuse, google-drive

After signing in to Google Chrome on Debian, I noticed that I had very little storage space. I found out that this was because my `/var/host/media/fuse/` folder contained a folder named `drivefs-` followed by a long alphanumeric. When I unmount the folder, a new one appears with a different alphanumeric.

In this folder there was a root folder containing the entire contents of my Google Drive, taking up several gigabytes.

I want to remove all of these files from my computer to free up some space.

Already tried deleting the entire drivefs file, but this also deleted all of my online files too. Now that I have restored the files from the trash, the folder is full of files again.

I tried pausing syncing on Chrome and [unchecking the box for syncing](https://www.wikihow.com/Stop-a-Google-Drive-Sync-on-PC-or-Mac#Disabling-All-Sync_sub) in Drive, but it still doesn't let me remove the files without deleting everything. Unchecking the box in Drive's settings doesn't remove any of the files.

Also, when I try to delete the `drivefs` file, it gives me an error, because I can't modify the two folders `Computers` or `.files-by-id`. Even the root user has only read privileges to these two folders.

I never installed any application for syncing my Drive account or granted any permissions for it, and when enabling sync, I choose only to sync passwords. I know that I don't have any Drive sync clients for Linux installed.

I did have the [Google Docs Offline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-offline/ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi) extension installed, but removing it does not remove the folder.

Based on some research I've done, I think it's a mounted filesystem using `FUSE`, but I still have no idea on how to remove it.

Here is the result of a tree command I ran:

```
/var/host/
├── chrome
│   ├── arc_bridge.sock
│   ├── wayland-0
│   └── wayland-0.lock
├── cras
├── cras-version
├── dbus
│   └── system_bus_socket
├── lsb-release
├── media
│   ├── archive
│   ├── fuse
│   │   └── drivefs-(alphanumeric)
│   │       ├── Computers
│   │       ├── root
│   │       │   ├── (all of my drive files)
|   │       └── team_drives
│   └── removable
```

In case it makes a difference, I am using Debian dual-booted on my chromebook with crouton.

**What I've tried**:
I ran `mount` on bash, and the drivefs folder was listed as `drivefs on /var/host/media/fuse/drivefs-(an) type fuse.drivefs
(rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=304,group_id=304,default_permissions,allow_other)`

Then I tried unmounting the directory from the chromebook side of my computer using this command in the CROSH shell:

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo fusermount -u /var/run/crouton/mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/xenial/var/host/media/fuse/drivefs-(alphanumeric)
```

The command didn't give any errors, but when I run `dir`, a new folder with a different alphanumeric at the end shows up, with the same contents. I think a program is mounting it again every time I remove it. Is there a log that would show what is happening?

Comment: How have you determined this folder is taking up the room on your system's storage? If the `fuse/drivefs-...` is a fuse mountpoint, then the files under it aren't necessarily taking up room on your computer

Comment: @Torin I used ncdu, how can I tell if it is using space?